# Is there an algorithm for Speaker Error Rate for speech-to-text diarization?

Tags: speech-to-text, transcription

Some speech-to-text services, like Google Speech-to-Text, offer speaker differentiation via diarization which attempts to identify and separate multiple speakers on a single audio recording. This is often needed when multiple speakers are in a meeting room sharing a single microphone.

Is there an algorithm and implementation to calculate the correctness of speaker separation?

This would be used in conjunction with [Word Error Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_error_rate) which is often used to test correctness of baseline transcription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly used approach for this appears to be the Diarization Error Rate (DER) defined by [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) in the NIST-RT projects.

A newer evaluation metric is the Jaccard Error Rate (JER) introduced in [DIHARD II: The Second DIHARD Speech Diarization Challenge](https://coml.lscp.ens.fr/dihard/index.html).

Two projects for measuring these include:

- https://github.com/nryant/dscore
- https://github.com/wq2012/SimpleDER

DER is referenced in these papers:

- [A Comparison of Neural Network Feature Transforms for Speaker Diarization](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/anndiar-is2015.pdf)
- [The ICSI RT-09 Speaker Diarization System](http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~fractor/papers/friedland_147.pdf)